# Trying to workaround a limitation of generated column in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

So I have been trying to generate duration column. But i recently found out that we cannot create virtual columns on non-repeatable/non deterministic functions http://mysqlserverteam.com/virtual-columns-and-effective-functional-indexes-in-innodb/. Can someone suggest a workaround. Im working my mysql CE server 5.7

```
`diagnosis_date` DATE NULL,
`disease_duration` TINYINT(2) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, diagnosis_date, curdate())) VIRTUAL;
```

Comment: Can the formatting be corrected?

Comment: Use a a view instead. Using a calculated column for this is a bad idea.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this scenario?